# Selling scripts/CMS modules on the internet

Tags: freelancing

While it's almost impossible to apply for a freelance job without a sufficient portfolio/work experience, I see selling my scripts as a solution. Problem is, so far I've seen only one forum, where such trade is going on - DigitalPoint. Are there any more +/- trusted places to offer your scripts for sale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla has a web app store that they are working on : https://apps.mozillalabs.com/

Google has it's Chrome Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore

Not sure about these, but ran across them:

http://codecanyon.net/ - PHP, Javascript, ASP.NET and Java

http://wpplugins.com/ - WordPress Plugins

http://www.sellascript.com - For Screen plays (you weren't specific :-p)